# Ошибка времени исполнения программы c++

Tags: стек

Есть задача, узнать, является ли скобочная последовательность правильной или нет.
Есть система, которая тестирует код. Так вот, выдаёт ошибку времени исполнения программы на третьем тесте. Доступа к тестам нет, вот код :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

inline bool LeftBracket(char c)
{
    return ('(' == c  || '[' == c);
}
inline bool Fit(char lb, char rb)
{
    return ('(' == lb && ')' == rb) || ('[' == lb && ']' == rb);
}

int main() {
    string arr = " ";
    string arr2 = " ";
    int i = 0;
    int j = -1;
    ifstream input("brackets.in");
    ofstream output("brackets.out");
        while(true){
            getline(input,arr);
            if(input.eof())
                break;
            if(arr.length() == 0){
                output << "YES" << endl;
            } else {

                for(int k = 1; k <= arr.length();k++) {
                    if(LeftBracket(arr[i])) {
                        ++j;
                        arr2[j] = arr[i];
                        ++i;
                    }
                    else if(j >= 0 && Fit(arr2[j],arr[i])) {
                        ++i;
                        --j;
                    }

                    else { 
                        j++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(j == -1) 
                    output << "YES" << endl;
                else
                    output << "NO" << endl;
                j = -1;
                i = 0;
                arr2 = " ";
                arr = " ";
            }
        }
    return 0;   
}
```

Смотрел ошибку с обращением к -1 элементу массива символов, такого быть не может, так как есть в условии, на всех тестах, которые я сам придумываю, программа работает корректно.Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После `getline(input,arr);` нужно выделить в стеке `arr2` память. Можно примерно так:

```
arr2.resize (arr.length(),' ');
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы правы, система приняла решение!